# C++: Runtime error with simple Recursive Search Function

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

So I have a program here that's supposed to do the very simple job of searching through an Array of 100 integers to find a specific key. The `linearSearch` function in this program is supposed to be recursive, so I have to call the function from within itself. The program compiles fine, but for some reason only returns the first element `0`, in the array no matter what search key you put in.
What am I not seeing? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int linearSearch(const int[], int, int);

int main()
{
    const int arraySize = 100; //size of array  
    int a[arraySize]; //create array a
    int searchKey; //value to locate in array a

    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            a[i] = 2 * i; //create data

    cout << "Enter integer search key: ";
    cin >> searchKey;

    //attempt to locate search key in array a
    int element = linearSearch(a, searchKey, arraySize);

    //display results
    if(element != -1)
               cout << "Found value in element: " << element << endl;
    else
               cout << "Value not found" << endl;

    system("pause");   
}

//linearSearch Function ****Returns 0 as index all the time *************
int linearSearch(const int array[], int key, int sizeOfArray)
{
    static int index = 0;

    //if Out of range, return -1 (Value not found)
    if(index >= sizeOfArray){return -1;}

    //if array value = key, array index is returned
    if(array[index] == key){return index;}

    //if array value is not equal to key, add to index and call func again                
    if(array[index] != key)
    {
                    index++;
                    linearSearch(array, key, sizeOfArray);                
    }   
}
```

I'm taking the correct approach by declaring `index` as `static`, right?

~Thanks a lot, you guys were quick and a HUGE help. =)

Comment: No, a `static` index is almost certainly a bad idea.  It's effectively a global variable which never gets reset.

Comment: 'Am I taking the right approach?' Definitely not, it should be a parameter.

Comment: No. It should be passed as a value parameter. Also, your function has no determinate return value on the tail-recurson resolution, so this stands no chance of working as is.

Comment: Surprisingly your code runs fine and gives correct results for me.

Comment: @stardust_ the behavior is undefined, since the function is being exited without a `return`.

Comment: Yep I saw that now. But just asking why should it be? index is static so return shouldn't affect its value as it is written now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also change your search function to the following without using static local variable `index`.

```
int linearSearch(const int array[], int index, int key, int sizeOfArray)
{
   //if Out of range, return -1 (Value not found)
   if(index >= sizeOfArray){return -1;}

   //if array value = key, array index is returned
   if(array[index] == key){return index;}

   //if array value is not equal to key, add to index and call func again                
    return linearSearch(array, index + 1, key, sizeOfArray);                
 }
```

The only change is that you are passing the starting index into the search function.

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is that

```
if(array[index] != key)
{
    index++;
    linearSearch(array, key, sizeOfArray);                
}
```

should be

```
if(array[index] != key)
{
    index++;
    return linearSearch(array, key, sizeOfArray);                
}
```

You don't return any value when the key is not equal.

Plus the static index is bad, as has already been said.

Comment: The whole `if` line can go as well.

Comment: Technically he doesn't have to return index there. Since it is static right now. As long as there is no code after that statement.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm taking the correct approach by declaring `index` as `static`, right?

No. Rather, `index` should be an argument to the recursive function.

Due to the `static` state, the function is hard to test and is not thread-safe. Furthermore, it inadvertently keeps state between invocations, meaning that if you were to call it a second time, it wouldn't work (since `index` would still have the old value).

Answer (score 1):

When doing this type of search recursively, you must propagate the index you're currently at in your array.

The way you're doing it, there's a global variable, `index` which *is the same in every call to your function* because of the static keyword.

The index should rather be a parameter, and each time you call the function recursively, you pass index+1 as a parameter.

Also, you must return the value of the recursive calls, otherwise it just does nothing and doesn't store/process the returned value.